# includegraphics in "BioMed Central's TeX template"

Tags: pdf, includegraphics

I'm using "BioMed Central's TeX template" ("BioMedCentral_article (ZIP format) - preferred template"), New+Content+Item.zip - you can find it with a WWW search. I add onto the empty line 56

```
\usepackage{graphics}
```

and add between lines 376 and 377 (within the `table` environment) the following line

```
\includegraphics{Table.pdf}
```

I expect the PDF figure to be embedded, but instead the text "Table.pdf" is added. How can I make the PDF included?

Comment: Use `\usepackage{graphicx}` not `\usepackage{graphics}`, plus do you have `draft` given as a class option? That will normally replace any figures by the file name they are trying you include.

Comment: @daleif Many thanks, (1) graphicx did the same, (2) the word "draft" doesn't occur in the file.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, I found a hint in the template file itself (bmc_article.tex):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                             %%
%%  If you wish to display your graphics for   %%
%%  your own use using includegraphic or       %%
%%  includegraphics, then comment out the      %%
%%  following two lines of code.               %%
%%  NB: These line *must* be included when     %%
%%  submitting to BMC.                         %%
%%  All figure files must be submitted as      %%
%%  separate graphics through the BMC          %%
%%  submission process, not included in the    %%
%%  submitted article.                         %%
%%                                             %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\includegraphic{}
\def\includegraphics{}
```

After commenting out lines 72 and 73 the figure got included.

Comment: This does not really answer your question, please extend it so we can at least see what one needed to uncomment. Note that you are also referring to files that we have no idea where to get.

Comment: It would really be helpful if you showed what those line are! There are three places to set the `draft` mode and "turn off" images: at `\documentclass[draft]{...}`; at package loading `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`; or at the command itself `\includegraphic[draft]{...}`. I am curious what else could cause your images to disappear.

Comment: The template contains `\def\includegraphics{}`.